# Why does Minecraft keep crashing in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I just installed Minecraft on my Ubuntu system using the Minecraft Installer Peeps PPA. When Minecraft finished downloading and was launched, it crashed and this is what I got:

```
    ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Daisy, daisy...

Time: 10/12/15 5:25 PM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ave.ar(SourceFile:560)
    at ave.am(SourceFile:361)
    at ave.a(SourceFile:310)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.getAvailableDisplayModes(LinuxDisplay.java:951)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.init(LinuxDisplay.java:738)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    ... 4 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at ave.ar(SourceFile:560)
    at ave.am(SourceFile:361)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at ave.a(SourceFile:310)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8.8
    Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 3.19.0-30-generic
    Java Version: 1.7.0_79, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 67187144 bytes (64 MB) / 158736384 bytes (151 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.8.8
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed openJDK?

Comment: @Aequitas Yes, I have openJDK installed.

Comment: the latest version? and you can try updating drivers see if that helps

Comment: [update lwjgl](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Update_LWJGL) or [this guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/177996/how-do-i-patch-minecrafts-lwjgl-libraries) (same thing just different guide)

Comment: I tried updating lwjql but it didn't work.

Comment: As for the drivers I am using the X.Org X one - do I switch it? There are a bunch of NVIDIA binary and legacy binary drivers

Comment: Please don't put solutions in your question.  If you solved it, feel free to write up an answer!

Comment: Whoops, sorry! I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Looks like it's an OpenGL issue. Try `sudo aptitude install freeglut3`
2. Check if you have the appropriate [backport](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) in your `sources.list`. I think that [Debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports) explains it better.
3. Check if you have OpenJDK 8 `sudo aptitude install openjdk-8-jre`
4. Uninstall OpenJDK 7 `sudo aptitude purge openjdk-7-jre`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're missing `XRandR`. You can get it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
```

For details, see [this forum thread](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5742.0).

Comment: Actually, I have it installed. When I typed in that command into terminal, it said I already had the newest version, so nothing was installed.

Comment: Huh, and `xrandr` works fine and prints out some displays? That's odd.

Comment: I can confirm that with a VERY similar crashreport, with Mageia 6, and with NVidia proprietary drivers installed and working, that installing xrandr fixed an "OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread." problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly you need Java 1.8 to run Minecraft 1.8 (and annoyingly you need Java 1.7 for Minecraft 1.7).  I ran into a similar problem on my system (Arch Linux) a while back and I think that's how I fixed it.  Search Java in the software center and the 1.8 version should come up, if not you may need to add a ppa since you're on an older version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I updated my Java version to 1.8.0_60 but the game still crashes? :/

Comment: You are wrong with MC 1.7, It works normally with Java 8...There was just one issue with Forge, what blocked using Java 8 on 1.6.X and early 1.7.X versions, but that got fixed years ago, too...There is not really problem to run MC 1.7 with Java 8.

Comment: ohh, oops!  I guess the only time that I tried running M.C. 1.7 with Java 1.8 was with Forge installed.

Answer (score -2):

It's probably you have too many apps or u need to get an unknown (to u) update. Or both. I've experienced that before and to manny apps on that divice is always my problem. Delete some apps and try again!!;)